# Question in the proof of theorem 7.3 (Evans' PDE)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence

In the proof of theorem 7.3 (Evans' PDE), the author asserted that
\begin{cases}
\boldsymbol{u}_{m_l} \rightharpoonup \boldsymbol{u} \quad \text{weakly in } L^2(0,T;H_0^1(U)) \\
\boldsymbol{u}_{m_l}' \rightharpoonup \boldsymbol{u}' \quad \text{weakly in } L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(U)) \\
\end{cases}

Then why
$$\int_0^T B[\boldsymbol{u}_{m_l},\boldsymbol{v};t]\,dt
\to \int_0^T B[\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v};t]\,dt\;$$

for $\boldsymbol{v}\in C^1([0,T]; H_0^1(U))$?
Note that $B$ is a bilinear form defined as follows
$$
B[u,v;t] = \int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{i,j}(x,t) u_{x_i} v_{x_j}
+ \sum_{i=1}^n b^i(x,t) u_{x_i} v + cuv\,dx.
$$

I know that $\boldsymbol{u}_{m_l} \rightharpoonup \boldsymbol{u}$ weakly in $L^2(0,T;H_0^1(U))$ means that for all $\boldsymbol{f}\in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(U))$ we have that

$$
\int_0^T \langle \boldsymbol{f}(t),\boldsymbol{u}_m(t)\rangle\,dt \to \int_0^T \langle \boldsymbol{f}(t),\boldsymbol{u}(t)\rangle\,dt.
$$

But how to use this to prove (for example the first integral term in the expression of $B$) that

$$
\int_0^T \int_U a^{i,j}(x,t)\bigl(\boldsymbol{u}_{m_l}(t)\bigr)_{x_i} (\boldsymbol{v}(t))_{x_j}\,dx\,dt
$$

converges to

$$
\int_0^T \int_U a^{i,j}(x,t)\bigl(\boldsymbol{u}(t)\bigr)_{x_i} (\boldsymbol{v}(t))_{x_j}\,dx\,dt
$$

as $m\to\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have a function $g\in L^2(U)$, then the linear function $L(v)=\int_Ug(x)v_{x_i}\,dx$, $v\in H^1_0(U)$, belongs to the dual space $H^{-1}(U)$, (just use Holder inequality to see this) and so if $v_k$ converges weakly to  $v$ in $H^1_0(U)$, then $$\int_Ug(x)(v_k)_{x_i}(x)\,dx\to \int_Ug(x)v_{x_i}(x)\,dx$$
Now assume you have dependence on time and integrate everything with respect to time.
Namely, if you have a function $g\in L^2(0,T;L^2(U))$, then the linear function $L(v)=\int_0^T\int_Ug(x,t)v_{x_i}(x ,t)\,dxdt,$ $v\in L^2(0,T;H^1_0(U))$, belongs to $L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(U))$, and so you can pass to the limit. Was this the question?